# ASP Repeater: to achieve same row height across all columns

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, repeater, row-height

I'm new here and new in web developing. I've been struggling with the repeater i made to display data from datatable. I have some data that are very long and some are short, these made my row height in different sizes and my borders kind of floating. I wanted the repeater to auto adjust the row height across all columns (whichever has the highest height) and apply vertical-align=middle. Please help me on how do i go about that. I'm using VB. Thank you in advance and have a good day.

```
<div id="div-repeater">
  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col1">text</div>
        <div class="col2">Data from Datatable</div>
        <div class="col3">Data from Datatable</div>
        <div class="col4">Data from Datatable</div>
      </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Comment: I would recommend using a CSS class for this.

Comment: Hi llya, i've done several changes in my css but it didnt work probably i was doing it the wrong since im just new to this programming. I've added my code to the post, i hope you could help me understand what you are trying to recommend to me. thanks so much.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to do this with an actual 'Table.'

Comment: If you want it to behave like a table, use a GridView control and set the rows to use a CSS class with `vertical-align:middle`.  Depending on what browsers you support, it's the only way to do this consistently.  (GridView renders to an html table).

Comment: well my boss doesnt want me to use table. he prefers that we use div. :( but if i wont be able to pull this off, maybe i will try the gridview.

Comment: While you can use javascript to align the rows, I advise against this. I understand most people are against using tables for page structure, but I do not see why displaying some data in a table is a bad idea.

Comment: i found this link (http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/).. exactly what i was looking for except that i need to apply this function to 3 different class (because its 3 repeaters)... almost done but not quite...

Comment: hi. i've done it, created one common class. thanks for all the advise.